# Não consigo fazer login com o google no meu app Release

Tags: android, firebase

neste trecho da `else` e não continua o login, já peguei a sha1 do Key store path pelo prompt como o codigo

`-list -v -keystore "Local da chave" -alias nomealias -storepass senha -keypass senha`

o app já esta até na playstore, antes estava funcionando de boa só foi fazer o release e mandar pra lá.

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(result.getSignInAccount());
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_log_in, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

> Neste momento irei refazer minha atividade de login caso não resolva posto meu codigo e espero uma luz aqui, ou mudo meu tipo de login algo que eu não quero :(

**ATUALIZÇÃO**
Rodei no debug e também não funcionou,
Refiz a atividade de login e voltou a funcinar, 
agora vou postar a nova versão do meu app e ver oque rola.

> Então... funciona no debug e na versão release mais na Playstore não funciona alguém me ajuda aí por favor.

Comment: Provavelmente estas usando a chave do debug-mode ao invés da chave do release-mode. Verifique o arquivo onde foram gravadas as chaves, adicione as chaves nas configurações do firebase, faça o download do novo google-services.json, grave no seu projeto na pasta do app e veja se faz o login.

Comment: Então eu larguei o app que eu estava fazendo, mais eu usei a chave release adicionei no firebase também mudei a chave no googleApi e não consegui, tanto que eu até mudei o tipo de login o que foi até melhor.enfim ,Obrigado!